# Ruby help understanding some control flow and putting multiple conditionals together

Tags: ruby, regex, parameters, conditional-statements, control-flow

I created a simple "banking program" as practice and it seemed to work well until I deliberately tried breaking it to see what happens.  I have a bit of code used to make sure that the pin is entered correctly.

I wanted to make one message appear if the entry did not include numbers, and I wanted to make another message pop up to determine whether or not the pin they entered was the pin associated to their account.  To do this I used an unless/else conditional followed by an if/else conditional (the first part of the code are some regexps referenced in the method and the hash where it's all stored):

```
@accounts = {
    "bob" => { :pin => 1234, :balance => -100 },
    "mark" => { :pin => 2345, :balance => 1000000000 }
}

# Makes sure the user only types exactly 4 digits
def valid_pin_entry(pin)
    /^\d{4}$/ === pin
end
# Makes sure the user only types digits
def valid_number_entry(number)
    /^\d+$/ === number
end

def enter_pin_number(username)
    puts "Please type your pin number."
    response = gets.chomp 

    unless valid_pin_entry(response)
        puts "Your response must be 4 numbers in length.\n\n"
        enter_pin_number(username)
    else
        pin = response.to_i
        puts "Validating pin number..."
    end
    if validate_pin(@username, pin)
        puts "Your pin was successfully entered!\n\n"
    else
        puts "The pin number you entered was incorrect.\n\n"
        enter_pin_number(@username)
    end
end
```

What seems to happen is that when the number is entered incorrectly, I call on the method to start over.  But it doesn't actually start over the way I thought it would.  The response I'm looking for would be something like:

"Your response must be 4 numbers in length."

"Please type your pin number."

(Entered correctly this time.)

"Validating pin number..."

"Your pin was successfully entered!"

But instead I wind up with this:

```
Please type your pin number.
 a
Your response must be 4 numbers in length.

Please type your pin number.
 2345
Validating pin number...
Your pin was successfully entered!

The pin number you entered was incorrect.

Please type your pin number.
 2345
Validating pin number...
Your pin was successfully entered!
```

I'm honestly having trouble understanding why this is happening in the first place and am thinking this has to deal with carrying the parameter back through the same method.  I managed to fix it using while to loop through responses, but that hasn't helped me understand my mistake.  My original program was riddled with these apparently, so I've posted it in a codecademy lab.

[My bank_account.rb code](http://labs.codecademy.com/CN5p/1#%3aworkspace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line, the code is calling the same function (another function call).

```
enter_pin_number(username)
```

Once that function call complete, the caller resume. To prevent resuming, you need to explicitly `return`.

```
unless valid_pin_entry(response)
    puts "Your response must be 4 numbers in length.\n\n"
    enter_pin_number(username)
    return # <------
else
    pin = response.to_i
    puts "Validating pin number..."
end
```

Comment: When you say the caller resumes, does that mean it picks up exactly where it left off and thus calls what's in the else function without going back through the beginning of unless?

Comment: @MarkHJr, No, it resume after the `enter_pin_number(username)` line: There's nothing after the line in the `unless` block; so it resume at `if validate_pin ..`.

Comment: After your change - the `else` keyword is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

When you decide to use recursion for your problem, make sure that no more code get executed after the return of a recursion call. In functional programming, it's called tail-recursion and can be optimized to a loop.

```
def enter_pin_number(username)
  puts "Please type your pin number."
  response = gets.chomp 

  unless valid_pin_entry(response)
    puts "Your response must be 4 numbers in length.\n\n"
    enter_pin_number(username)
  else
    pin = response.to_i
    puts "Validating pin number..."

    if validate_pin(@username, pin)
      puts "Your pin was successfully entered!\n\n"
    else
      puts "The pin number you entered was incorrect.\n\n"
      enter_pin_number(@username)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This comment was very helpful in that you introduced me to the terminology of recursion.  That being said, the code only helped stopped what was happening when I called enter_pin_number from within the unless conditional.  To really fix the problem I was facing, I needed to explicitly return, which solved the problems in the rest of the code as well.  I still appreciate your help greatly.  I found a host of new information.

Comment: @MarkHJr the modification I posted is just identical with the ***explicit return*** version. I'm not sure why you still have problem...

Comment: Sorry, you're correct.  I had another recursion problem going on elsewhere that caused it.  I can't seem to figure out how to apply what you did to other code.  Using return it's pretty obvious so that fixed all my other recursion problems, but you put the if statement inside the else part of the unless statement, which I couldn't figure out how to apply to just a normal conditional that calls on itself in one option and continues in the other.  It seems like in that situation I have to use the explicit return.